# Issues With Unty3d's Random.Range - I don't understand why it's behaving this way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

So, I'm generating a Vector2 using Unity's Random.Range, this is basically the x and y value of the direction the mobile should be moving.

```
    m_CurrentMovementInput = new Vector2
        (Random.Range(-0.75f, 0.75f), Random.Range(-0.75f, 0.75f));
```

The problem is the mobiles are only moving in diagonal angles. Which makes it seem like when it produces the random it's producing like..

*(-0.35f, -0.35f) or (0.35f, -0.35f) or (-0.35f, 0.35f)*

Which makes little sense to me as I understand the random function.

I'm sure I can get the desired behaviour by only changing one at a time, but I'd still like to understand its current behavior.

**Edit:** I believe this is all the relevant code. Sorry it took so long had to go get it from the repo.

```
void ProcessMovement()
{
    ModifyComputerMovement(m_CurrentMovementInput.x, m_CurrentMovementInput.x);
}

float ModifyMovementInput(float input)
{
    return input * m_MovementSpeedBase;
}

void RandomizeMovementInput()
{
    m_CurrentMovementInput = new Vector2
        (Random.Range(-0.75f, 0.75f), Random.Range(-0.75f, 0.75f));

    if(RandomBoolean)
    {
        m_CurrentMovementInput += new Vector2
            (Random.Range(-0.05f, 0.05f), Random.Range(-0.05f, 0.05f));
    }
}

void ModifyComputerMovement(float x, float y)
{
    m_VerticalInput = x;
    m_HorizontalInput = y;

    if ((m_VerticalInput == 0 && m_HorizontalInput == 0))
    {
        m_IsMoving = false;
    }

    else { m_IsMoving = true; }

    UpdateCpuLocation();
}

bool m_ShouldRun;
bool m_ShouldSprint;
void UpdateCpuLocation()
{
    if (!IsMoving())
        m_CurrentMoveType = MovementType.None;
    else
        m_CurrentMoveType = MovementType.Walk;

    m_DeltaVector = new Vector3
    (
        ModifyMovementInput(m_VerticalInput),
        m_IsJumping ? ComputeJumpVelocity() : ApplyGravity(),
        ModifyMovementInput(m_HorizontalInput)
    );

    m_GammaVector =
        transform.forward * m_DeltaVector.x + transform.right * m_DeltaVector.z;

    m_DeltaVector = new Vector3
        (m_GammaVector.x, m_DeltaVector.y, m_GammaVector.z);

    if (m_ShouldRun && IsMoving())
    {
        if (m_Controller.isGrounded)
        {
            m_CurrentMoveType = MovementType.Run;
            m_DeltaVector *= m_RunSprintFactor;

            if (m_ShouldSprint && IsMoving())
            {
                m_CurrentMoveType = MovementType.Sprint;
                m_DeltaVector *= m_RunSprintFactor;
            }
        }
    }

    m_VectorShift = !m_Controller.isGrounded ?
            (m_DeltaVector * Time.deltaTime) * m_JumpModifier : (m_DeltaVector * Time.deltaTime);

    if (m_Controller.isGrounded)
        m_VectorShift *= (m_PlayerState.GetCurrentEnergyLevelRatio());

    m_VectorShift = new Vector3
        (
            m_VectorShift.x,
            m_VectorShift.y,
            m_VectorShift.z
        );

    #region Debug
    //Debug.Log("Vector Shift: " + m_VectorShift);
    //Debug.Log("Vector Shift Breakdown:");
    /*Debug.Log
        (String.Format
            ("VectorShift (X): {0} | VectorShift (Y): {1} | VectorShift (Z): {2}", 
                (double)m_VectorShift.x, (double)m_VectorShift.y, (double)m_VectorShift.z));*/
    #endregion

    if (m_PlayerState.GetCurrentEnergyLevelRatio() < m_MinimumEnergyThreshold)
        m_VectorShift *= m_LowStamMoveModulus;

    //m_MoveEventArg =
        //new PlayerMoveActionEventArgs(m_VectorShift, GetCurrentMovementType);
    if (m_IsMoving)
    {
        //EventDispatcher.InvokeMoveAction(m_MoveEventArg);
    }

    m_VectorShift = m_VectorShift * (Time.deltaTime * m_TimeWarpModifier);
    m_Controller.Move(m_VectorShift);
}
```

> Edit, Part II

So, the only thing that is really different is this:

```
void QueryPlayerInput()
{
    m_VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    m_HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if ((m_VerticalInput == 0 && m_HorizontalInput == 0))
    {
        m_IsMoving = false;
    }

    else {  m_IsMoving = true; }

    UpdatePlayerLocation();
}
```

Comment: This is unexpected from your code, please provide more info

Comment: I'll try to figure out what other information I can get you. I still haven't figured out why it's happening but I've kind of put a bandaid on it for now by added the vector to transform.forward. I guess I could get video of their movement with the debug log. Sigh.

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with random, maybe the way you move objects is causing this diagonal movement problem

Comment: @Bijan - Yeah, I really wouldn't think so either. I updated everything pertaining to movement.

Comment: shouldn't `m_DeltaVector = new Vector3(m_GammaVector.x, m_DeltaVector.y, m_GammaVector.z);` be `m_DeltaVector = new Vector3(m_GammaVector.x, m_GammaVector.y, m_GammaVector.z);`

Comment: The would effectively disable gravity/jumping. That's another reason I'm so confused. It's literally a copy of a working player controller, the only thing I'm doing is feeding in a random float instead of gathering the input axis...

Comment: @Bijan - Added another code block in the question, it's essentially the different between the computer movement and the player movement and the player movement give me 0 problems.

Comment: I wonder why ProcessMovement() uses two times the same parameter: m_CurrentMovementInput.x

Comment: @JeffRSon - Hahahaha. Dude, you're a life saver. I can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: It actually explains a lot, rofl! Thank you.